# Ошибка syntaxerror: non-utf-8 code starting with '\xf2' in file как исправить

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Коллеги, добрый день!
Возникла такая проблема.
Написал бота для телеграмма в пайчарме на Ubuntu.
При попытке запуска возникает ошибка syntaxerror: non-utf-8 code starting with '\xf2'
При запуске кода на винде 10 в пайчрме - всё отлично работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?
Всю документацию прочитал, все #! .--. UTF8 и подобные прописывал. Ни чего не помогает.
Ни в линуксе, ни в винде нет кириллических букв в папках с пайтоном (виртуальным окружением).
Спасибо!

Comment: Пересохранить код в utf-8.

Comment: Возможно BOM сигнатура наличествует?

Comment: Это русская `т` в кодировке windows cp1251. Проверьте, в какой кодировке сохранены исходники

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Дмитрий, тут появилась я так понял новая проблема. Да, кодировка была cp1251 я поменял ее в Пайчарме на utf-8. Но появилась новая проблема, на винде код запускается а на удаленном сервере linux нет! Выдает ошибку на одной из строк кода. Я не знаю что делать.

Comment: какая ошибка теперь?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/pythonProject/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Comment: На старой кодировке все работало

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951712/telebot-object-has-no-attribute-message-handler

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Друзья, всем спасибо за помощь, всё заработало!